# Why is makecontext not calling my function?

Tags: c, ucontext

My program contains the line:

```
 makecontext( &threadList[ numThreads ].context, (void (*)(void)) &threadStart, 1, 5);
```

Where *threadStart()* is defined as:

```
      static void threadStart(int x){
      printf("Yes! Yes! %d\n", x);
 }
```

I thought this should result in the display of "Yes! Yes! 5", but this does not happen. I'm not sure what is happening. I know the line is running, since I have a print statement just below it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The function is only called when the context gets activated by `setcontext()` or `swapcontext()`

[makecontext(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/makecontext.3.html)